# Populate() works in console, but not in controller

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I cannot, for the life of me, figure this one out.
If I run `sails console` and input the following code:

```
User.findOne(1).populate('schools').exec(console.log)
// logs user data and schools is populated`
```

Then I get the results that I expect.
However, when I run the exact same code inside a controller, I still get all the user info, but `schools` is an empty array.

routes.js:

`'GET /getSchools': 'UserController.getSchools'`

UserController.js:

```
module.exports = {
  getSchools: function(req, res) {
    User.findOne(1).populate('schools').exec(console.log)
    // logs user data but schools is empty array
  }
}
```

Why would that be the case and how do I get it to work in the controller?

**EDIT:** This issue was caused because my local copy of Sails (in my node_modules folder) was version 0.11.1 while my global Sails was version 0.11.0. Reverting the Sails in my node_modules folder to be 0.11.0 fixed the issue. I hope this helps anyone else whose console environment is behaving differently than their controller environment. Thanks @sgress454!

Comment: Please share more detail, such as code in your controller, what you have there that DOES work and is similar, what you have tried (in controller and in console, signs of reasearch and detail on prior efforts is absolutely required for every single new question) and current vs expected output. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DanielBrose I tried to be scarce on details, but i did provide the code that matters

Comment: See if you can ask your question in here: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails . They can probably help you out as well.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `sails console` _always_ uses the globally installed Sails, whereas `sails lift` or `node app.js` will use the _locally installed_ Sails if available (i.e. if there's a `node_modules/sails` folder in your project).  If you do have a locally-installed Sails, try running `./node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js console` and see if you get the same results as when lifting.

Comment: @sgress454 Very insightful! I ran the code in the node_modules and it failed. I checked the versions, and my local sails was 0.11.1 while my global sails was 0.11.0.
I reverted my local to be 0.11.0 and that did the trick!

Comment: @DavidMoritz - pls include that edit content (ie solution) in an self-answer and accept, so this no longer flagged as 'unanswered'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused because my local copy of Sails (in my node_modules folder) was version 0.11.1 while my global Sails was version 0.11.0. Reverting the Sails in my node_modules folder to be 0.11.0 fixed the issue. I hope this helps anyone else whose console environment is behaving differently than their controller environment. Thanks @sgress454!